# R for Data Science Chapter 2.2.2 Already getting error messages before I've started

Tags: r

I have just started Reading R for data science.

I uploaded tidyverse, palmer penguins and ggthemes

```
palmerpenguins::penguins
ggplot(data = penguins)
```

> Error in .standalone_types_check_dot_call(ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7,  :
> object 'ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7' not found

Can anyone tell me what I'm already doing wrong?
Much appreciated.

Comment: That's quite an unusual error ... by "uploaded" do you mean that you loaded the packages, i.e. `library("tidyverse"); library("palmerpenguins")` ?

Comment: There [is a function with that name in ggplot2](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/search?q=standalone_types_check_dot_call).  My **guess** is that you should start a clean R session, re-install the `rlang` package (`install.packages("rlang")`), then re-install ggplot2 (`install.packages("ggplot2")`), then cross your fingers.

Comment: The function that you've linked to isn't in 3.2.1 (current CRAN version) but will be part of 3.2.2.

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading from R 4.2.2 to 4.2.3. The reason was, that we use an extended R installer (created with Innosetup) in our organisation than has a set of most common packages included. Its installation resulted in two versions of `rlang` with the recent 1.1.0 in the system library and an outdated 1.0.6 version in the user library. The usual `update.packages()` did not help. Finally. it could be fixed by removing `rlang`  from the user library with RStudios package manager.

Answer (score 8):

Edit:

gtable 0.3.3 has hit CRAN and will soon be available in all mirrors. You can update gtable as follows:

```
install.packages("gtable")
```

Old answer:

There isn't anything wrong with your code. There is however an issue with the underlying {gtable} package that uses functions from {rlang} 1.1.0, but doesn't declare this in the package's DESCRIPTION file. This manifests when using {ggplot2} combined with earlier versions of {rlang}. The release candidate of {ggplot2} includes a version requirement bump for {rlang}, which should dissolve these errors, but is still a few weeks out.

In the meantime, you should be able to resolve this by installing the latest version of {rlang}:

```r
install.packages("rlang")
```

or by downgrading the {gtable} package:

```r
devtools::install_version("gtable", version = "0.3.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

The relevant issue tracked by ggplot is [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5235).

Answer (score 7):

Since there are several deleted "same here!" questions, I'll write up my comment as an answer. This error suggests some kind of incompatibility between the installed version of the `rlang` and `ggplot2` packages.  I would try

- start a **clean** R session (no non-default packages loaded)
- re-install `rlang` (`install.packages("rlang")`)
- re-install `ggplot2` (`install.packages("ggplot2")`)